# Проверка на работу Мемкэша

Tags: php

Приветствую

Есть memcache и memcached. Не всегда они установлены на хостинге, так что хотел замутить процедуру проверки, но, как проверить то, работают они или нет? Нашел только туповатый способ, через трай-кэч. 2й способ - распарсить созданную страницу phpinfo. А есть ли какой то стандартный способ позволяющий проверить поддерживается ли memcache и memcached?

p.s. допустим что то в роде:

```
if($_PHP['сервак,_ты_поддерживаешь_мемкэш?']=true){
    $my='да';
}else{
    $my='нет';
}
echo $my;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to check if memcache or memcached is installed for PHP?](https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+how+to+check+if+memcached+is+installed)
[первая ссылка на странице](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463670/how-to-check-if-memcache-or-memcached-is-installed-for-php)

> You can look at phpinfo() or check if
>   any of the functions of memcache is
>   available. Ultimately, check whether
>   the Memcache class exists or not.
>
> e.g.
>
> if(class_exists('Memcache')){   //
>   Memcache is enabled. }

Comment: эх.. май энглиш вери бад. сенкс! Правда их там 2, ..cache и ..cached, но это уже найду